# How to make maven appassembler use javaw instead of java in generated scripts

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-3, appassembler

Is it possible to make maven appassembler plugin to generate startup scripts that use 'javaw'  instead of 'java'?

Answer (score 3):

In Appassembler 1.3 you can do it by configuring the `showConsoleWindow` option in the POM:

```
<showConsoleWindow>flase</showConsoleWindow>
```

This will change the line in the resulting Script from

```
if "%JAVACMD%"=="" set JAVACMD=java
```

to this

```
if "%JAVACMD%"=="" set JAVACMD=start /min javaw
```

Comment: A small downside is is that you can only specify this in the general `<configuration>` of the plugin, not for every `<program>`.